# Is there an equivalent to MySql's getLastInsertID() in MongoDb & PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb

The title asks it all.
I have found an example that looked something like this:

```
db.find(fields = {"-id"}).sort("-id", -1).limit(X)
```

but that doesn't seem safe because that is assuming the ids will actually be in order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$item = array( ... );
$mongo_collection->insert($item);
$id = $item['_id'];
```

It'll add the ID to the $item array. Also note you can use an object instead of an array if it's your preference.

Comment: Basically, to clarify all MongoDB drivers generate the "_id" on the client side, although the server is *capable* of generating them.  This way you will always have the generated ID available immediately from your code.  This includes PHP, as David has shown.